# How do I remove specific components from the sidemenu?

Tags: codenameone

I added components to sidemenu by the code below

```
getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(btn1)
```

How do I remove btn1 from sidemenu?

Comment: Instead of adding `btn1` directly to the `Toolbar`, you can first  add it to a `Container`. Then add this `Container` as the toolbar component. Lastly you can remove `btn1` from the `Container` using `removeComponent` function and revalidate the container to apply changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an omission in the API that probably should be corrected. Typically side menus aren't modified and at most, things are disabled so there was no request for this functionality.